# How to read csv files and set values to TextView using OpenCsv?

Tags: android, arrays, csv, opencsv

I have a csv file with only one column of values. I would like to take the values from each row and display them in separate TextViews using OpenCSV. My code goes something like this:

```
try {
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvInPath));
        String [] row;
        while ((row = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            tvN[1].setText(row[1].toString());
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It gives me an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error in LogCat and the app force closes.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to do this right? Thanks.

Comment: Then post rhe logcat. What is tvN ? What is tvN[1]? It makes no sense to use tvN[1] in a loop. Did you mean tvN[i] or someting like that? If there is only one cullumn then row[1] is non existing. Use row[0] instead.

Comment: Oh! I was under the impression that OpenCSV reads row by row ie. row[0] represents the first row and row[1] represents the second row, etc. I guess it reads columns?

Comment: Well what does readNext return? And how often can it be called? You can easily find out. I think it will reed one row every time. But that is just my guess. You can find out. If String row[] represents a row then row[0] is the first (and your only) collumn. So you better had named it String collumns[].

Answer (score 0):

As greenapps pointed out, I was referencing to row[1], which does not exist, as I only have 1 *column* of values. Turns out OpenCSV reads csv files column by column, and since I had only 1 column, I had to either use row[0], or make my csv have multiple columns. ie:
My csv file:

1. Name1
2. Name 2
3. Name 3

What I should use:
 1. Name  2. Name2  3. Name3

It would also be better to rename row[] to column[] to avoid any confusion.